# Replace specific characters within a string

Tags: javascript, replace

**NOTE:** This is not a duplicate. I have searched everywhere and have not gotten an answer.

I want to take a certain string (`[0;14;32m`) and no matter what the numbers are, always replace that string with nothing. I have tried everything and haven't found a solution.

Comment: You mean all the strings have the same pattern? [N;NN;NNm ? You need to look at regex matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.replace(/\[\d;\d{2};\d{2}m/, "")`

http://bit.ly/1cjUUBL

Comment: Why am I being voted down? This is an answer to his question, regardless of how trivial or easily available it is.

Comment: Thanks. I never really understood regexes.